# Selecting only those levels of a factor which appear in each level of other factor

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, filtering, data-manipulation

I wan to select only those levels of `Trt` which appear in each level of `Loc` (commonly appear in level of `Loc` for every large data set).

```
Loc <- rep(paste0("L", 1:2), c(6, 4))
Trt <- c(rep(paste0("T", 1:3), times = 2), rep(paste0("T", 1:2), times = 2))
set.seed(12345)
Y   <- c(rnorm(n=5, mean = 50, sd = 5), NA, rnorm(n=4, mean = 50, sd = 5)) 
df1 <- data.frame(Loc, Trt, Y)
df1

   Loc Trt        Y
1   L1  T1 52.92764
2   L1  T2 53.54733
3   L1  T3 49.45348
4   L1  T1 47.73251
5   L1  T2 53.02944
6   L1  T3       NA
7   L2  T1 40.91022
8   L2  T2 53.15049
9   L2  T1 48.61908
10  L2  T2 48.57920
```

**Required Output**

```
   Loc Trt        Y
   L1  T1 52.92764
   L1  T2 53.54733
   L1  T1 47.73251
   L1  T2 53.02944
   L2  T1 40.91022
   L2  T2 53.15049
   L2  T1 48.61908
   L2  T2 48.57920
```

This can be achieved using

```
    library(dplyr)
    df1 %>% filter(Trt != "T3")
```

Here I know the patter of appearance. I am looking for more general solution.

Comment: None of the levels of `Trt` appears in `Loc`. Maybe one of the `paste0` that defines `Trt` should have a `"L"` and not two times a `"T"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another idea with base R. We split `Trt` based on `Loc` and use `Reduce` with `intersect` to find all common elements. We use those elements to index the original data frame, i.e.

```
i1 <- Reduce(intersect, split(df1$Trt, df1$Loc))
df1[df1$Trt %in% i1,]
```

which gives,

> ```
>   Loc Trt        Y
> 1   L1  T1 52.92764
> 2   L1  T2 53.54733
> 4   L1  T1 47.73251
> 5   L1  T2 53.02944
> 7   L2  T1 40.91022
> 8   L2  T2 53.15049
> 9   L2  T1 48.61908
> 10  L2  T2 48.57920
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially trying to figure out which `df1$Trt`-values exist in every level of `df1$Loc`. There are probably some nice ways to do it in `dplyr`, that I'm not aware of. In base `R` you could do:

```
dirty <- lapply( levels(df1$Loc), function(x) df1$Trt[df1$Loc == x])
clean <- do.call(intersect, dirty)

df1[df1$Trt %in% clean, ]
#    Loc Trt        Y
# 1   L1  T1 52.92764
# 2   L1  T2 53.54733
# 4   L1  T1 47.73251
# 5   L1  T2 53.02944
# 7   L2  T1 40.91022
# 8   L2  T2 53.15049
# 9   L2  T1 48.61908
# 10  L2  T2 48.57920
```

In the last step you could also stick to your `dplyr` solution:

```
df1 %>% filter(Trt %in% clean)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken S. for your answer. I guess you missed some code in your answer. What are `intersect` and `Trtvals`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, a possible solution is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, uniqueN(Loc), by = Trt][V1 == df1[, uniqueN(Loc)]], on = "Trt"][, -"V1"]
```

> ```
>    Loc Trt        Y
> 1:  L1  T1 52.92764
> 2:  L1  T1 47.73251
> 3:  L2  T1 40.91022
> 4:  L2  T1 48.61908
> 5:  L1  T2 53.54733
> 6:  L1  T2 53.02944
> 7:  L2  T2 53.15049
> 8:  L2  T2 48.57920
> ```

#### Explanation

The total number of unique levels of `Loc` is

```
df1[, uniqueN(Loc)]
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

The number of unique levels of `Loc` in each `Trt` is

```
df1[, uniqueN(Loc), by = Trt]
```

> ```
>    Trt V1
> 1:  T1  2
> 2:  T2  2
> 3:  T3  1
> ```

The levels of `Trt` which contain all levels of `Loc` are

```
df1[, uniqueN(Loc), by = Trt][V1 == df1[, uniqueN(Loc)]]
```

> ```
>    Trt V1
> 1:  T1  2
> 2:  T2  2
> ```

Now, this right joined with `df1` and the helper column removed from the result:

```
df1[df1[, uniqueN(Loc), by = Trt][V1 == df1[, uniqueN(Loc)]], on = "Trt"][, -"V1"]
```